# Using a custom hadoop Input Format Jar in Apache Drill

Tags: hadoop, azure-table-storage, apache-drill

I'm trying to use a hadoop input format wrapper for Azure Table that someone wrote in github:
https://github.com/mooso/azure-tables-hadoop

I know it works in Apache Flink as shown in this example: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/azure_table_storage/

My guess is that it must look something similar to using Google Storage plugin for hadoop:

For example my core-site.xml has among others this setting for Google FS:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl</name>
    <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS</value>
    <description>The AbstractFileSystem for gs: uris.</description>
</property>
```

And the corresponding storage plugin json has among others, the following properties:

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "connection": "gs://...",
  "workspaces":
...
}
```

So my question is,
after installing the jar file in the jars folder in drill.
what is the expected storage plugin configuration that I could use to "use" the previously mentioned wrapper?

Has someone already done this?
Do I understand correctly the idea of using the hadoop input format as a jar in drill?

thanks in advance

Jorge